# modify es6 promise typings by adding exceptions to PromiseLike

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

**Why? To find errors in a large code base, where `ng.IPromise` and `Promise` are mixed together.**

I have already done that for ng.IPromise typings by modifying this:

```
interface IPromise<T> {
    then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<TResult>|TResult, errorCallback?: null | undefined, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
    // ...
}
```

to this:

```
interface IPromise<T> {
    then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<TResult>|TResult, errorCallback?: null | undefined, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): TResult extends Promise<any> ? never : IPromise<TResult>;
    // ...
}
```

But native Promise typings are more complex, cause it introduces a PromiseLike type to resolve result of any object which has a `then` method:

```
interface PromiseLike<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>;
}

interface Promise<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
}
```

And I want to achieve a behavior, where **every `PromiseLike` except an `ng.IPromise` resolves**.

Have tried to simplify the typings to better understand them. So basically we can simplify the problem to smth like this - how to modify the following typings:

```
interface Bar<T> {
    then<K>(f: (value: T) => K | Bar<K>): Bar<K>;
}

interface PartialFoo<T> {
    then<K>(f: (value: T) => K | PartialFoo<K>): PartialFoo<K>;
}

interface Foo<T> {
    then<K>(f: (value: T) => K | PartialFoo<K>): Foo<K>;
}
```

so that:

```
let a: Foo<string>;
let b: PartialFoo<number>;
let c: Bar<number>;

let x: Foo<string> = a.then(() => a); // is ok
let y: Foo<number> = a.then(() => b); // is ok
let z: never = a.then(() => c); // returns type never, so chaining anything else will give an error
```

Also another thing, where I don't really understand how Typescript works, why when modifying interfaces in this way:

```
interface PartialFoo<T> {
    then<K>(f: () => K | PartialFoo<K>): PartialFoo<K>;
}

interface Foo<T> {
    then<K>(f: () => K | PartialFoo<K>): Foo<K>;
}

let a: Foo<string>;
let x = a.then(() => a);
```

type for `x` is `Foo<Foo<string>>`, but in case of:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    then<K>(f: () => K | Foo<K>): Foo<K>;
}
```

it's still resolved to `Foo<string>`. What role `value: T` is playing, if it's not even used?